# Colors in Instruments when hunting down memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm currently hunting down a memory leak in my app for iPhone. I'm using Instruments to track down the code that is causing the leak (becoming more and more a friend of Instruments!). Now Instruments show two lines: one in dark blue (row 146) and one in a lighter blue (150). From some trial and error I get that they are connected somehow, but not good enough at Objective-C and Memory Management yet to really understand how.

Does anyone know why different colors are used and what could be my problem?

I have tried to release numberForArray but the the app crashes when showing the last line in a picker view.

All ideas appreciated!

[image]

(Posting this I also realize that line 139 is redundant! Se there, already an improvement ;-)

Comment: Always explicitly initialize your variables even if your language does it for you.  It gets confusing when you switch between languages or when other people look at your code or when you put a loop around your code.  There's absolutely no performance penalty since modern compilers will just take it out if it's redundant.

Comment: @colithium I don't disagree with this advice, but I don't see how it applies to this question. The only variable declaration in the code show is on line 140, and that does include initialization...

Comment: "Posting this I also realize that line 139 is redundant! Se there, already an improvement"

I assumed that's what he meant by this line in the question.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. In this instance, I think it's not a case of "the language doing it for you" so much as the OP realizing that the variable always gets assigned in the for loop before being used, so setting it to 0 before entering the loop is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, lets take a look at the object allocation/ownership behavior of this code...

`numberForArray` is assigned the result of `-NSString stringWithFormat:`, which is an auto-released object. That means that you do **not** want to release it (as you discovered).

That object is then added to the `glucoseLoader` NSMutableArray, which will `retain` it. You loop 100 times, creating 100 objects and adding them to `glucoseLoader`. When `glucoseLoader` is released, at line 154, it will also release all the objects added to it.

But wait, there's more: `firstComponentRange` is created from `glucoseLoader` using `-NSArray initWithArray:`. When you do that, all the elements of the source array are added to the destination, which will retain them again.

So, when/how do you release `firstComponentRange`?

Comment: Thanks David for the informative and correct answer. I was going crazy for a while with this, missing (forgot) the thing about the autorelease.

I use the firstComponentRange in a picker, so now I release that array in viewWillDisappear. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is telling you that firstComponentRange is not being released (a small leak). Since the array retains its contents, you ate thus also leaking 100 NSString instances, allocated at the line indicated with a darker band (a more significant leak).

Comment: Hi Barry

Thanks. I was going on that line of thought, which unfortunately led me to look at the problems in the wrong order. As you can see in my reply to David, the real issue was with my firstComponentRange. I'm now leak free :-)

But I guess thats how it is. You learn by doing...